# JavaFx: Path to Image

Tags: java, image, javafx, file-io

I am trying to create a button with an IMG on it using JFX.

For some reason no matter what path I try, Eclipse can not seem to locate my Icon.png

the path is

```
C:\Users\name\eclipse-workspace\project\lib\Icon.png
```

I have tried

```
Image icon= new Image("lib\Icon.png");
Image icon= new Image("lib\\Icon.png");
Image icon= new Image("/lib/Icon.png");
Image icon= new Image("//lib//Icon.png");

new ImageView("//C:/Users/name/eclipse-workspace/project/lib/Icon.png");

 String imgpath="C:\\Users\\name\\eclipseworkspace\\project\\lib\\libIcon.png";
        try {
            BufferedImage myimg=ImageIO.read(new File(imgpath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

None of these can seem to find the Img.. any idea why? Perhaps there is something I need to configure with eclipse?

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: I dont understand why but try {
   FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream("lib/Icon.png");
   image= new Image(input);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); ended up working.. if someone could explain?

Comment: You need to post the whole folder structure. Put `lib` under `src` folder and use  `new ImageView("/lib/Icon.png");`

Comment: If the URL `String` passed to the `Image` or `ImageView` constructor does not have a scheme (e.g. `file:`) then it interprets the path as relative to the _root_ of the classpath. If you don't have your image on the classpath at runtime then Java can't find it.  For instance, if you had `new ImageView("file:///C:/Users/name/eclipse-workspace/project/lib/Icon.png")` it'd likely work; don't do this, however, as it doesn't access the image as a resource and thus won't be portable. Look up how to include resources in Eclipse (or your build tool of choice if using one) and act accordingly.